# How to reconstruct index and cache while reinstalling eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, caching, indexing

I have caches and index (indices) for different project in my eclipse kepler. Now if I reinstall the same eclipse version would I have to reconstruct all index and cache? If not, how do I save for the new version?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the indices that Eclipse manages, these are stored in the `.metadata` folder in your workspace. Because they are in the workspace reinstalling Eclipse will not affect them.